# how to change behaviour of Jdeveloper expecting files in weblogic default domain

Tags: java, path, weblogic, jdeveloper

I am using `Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.0` and developing Oracle adf web application. The default domain of **weblogic server** is `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\DefaultDomain\`.
It is expecting all files in this default domain location only. It is not reading from the project. So how to change this behaviour so that it can read from the project current path.

Will any one help on this issue.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. The embedded wls server is installed at this position so it reads from there. Jdev installed applications you run or debug there too. What would you like to do?

Comment: I am using  xsl files and calling all xsl files from one main xsl file.  From this  line
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/check.xsl").getPath(), i can able to call main xsl. But the issue here is by defaultly path coming as default domain for remaining xsl which are imported in main xsl. If i place all files in default domain its working fine. I want to change that path to current path.

Comment: I want to change the default domain path to current file path for all files in current project so that there wont be any path issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the path from any image file then use that path to set the user.dir. 
Here getAbsoluteFile() and getAbsolutePath() plays a vital role.

```
String path=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/samp.png").getPath();
File directory = new File(path).getAbsoluteFile();
    System.out.println("***directory*" + directory.getAbsolutePath());

    if (directory.exists()) {
        System.setProperty("user.dir", directory.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```